# R data transformation, aggregation

Tags: r, dplyr, transformation, reshape, reshape2

I'm trying to transform the following data frame from:

```html
<table border = 1>
<tr>
  <td>id</td>
  <td>code</td>
  <td>status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>041</td>
  <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>056</td>
  <td>NC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>123</td>
  <td>036</td>
  <td>NC</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>075</td>
  <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>059</td>
  <td>C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>039</td>
  <td>NC</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>456</td>
  <td>021</td>
  <td>NC</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

to like as follows: (in a way i'm trying to pivot my results on the Status field, however given that the code is string, I want to concatenate the codes that fall under that status.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>nc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>041</td>
    <td>056;036</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>456</td>
    <td>075;059</td>
    <td>039;021</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried to use reshape/reshape2 as well, however, I'm not getting success. Can anyone suggest any methods that can assist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

was able to figure it out. 
using dyplr package.

```
group_by, summarise and mutate commands
```

Thank you!